# Unable to fetch variable from a lib in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an RoR app that fetch my Netbox instance (an open-source IPAM) to show our virtual machines.

I use a netbox Lib in ruby (https://github.com/ninech/netbox-client-ruby), it work as well but I got issues to fetch a variable.

Maybe it's my low level in Ruby the cause, but I don't find any answer.

## I fetch VMs in my Controller

```
vms = NetboxClientRuby.virtualization.virtual_machines.filter(cluster_id: cluster_id)
```

## I use the @vms var in my ERB html files

```
 <% @vms.each do |vm| %>
        <tr>
# This Work well
            <td><%= vm.name %></td>
            <td><%= vm.vcpus %></td>
            <td><%= vm.memory %>Mo</td>
            <td><%= vm.disk %>Go</td>
# This doesn't work
            <td> <%= vm.primary_ip.address %></td>   
        </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have tried `vm.primary_ip['address'], vm.primary_ip('address')` and few other way, but I'm unable to get my VM Primary IP Address.

I got error like this :

```
undefined method `address' for #NetboxClientRuby::IPAM::IpAddress:0x00007ffff51d63c8
```

Any idea ?

The Json Object from the lib look like this :

```
{"id"=>159,
 "name"=>"VM1", 
 "status"=>{"value"=>"active", "label"=>"Active", "id"=>1}, 
 "tenant"=>nil, 
 "primary_ip"=>{"id"=>916, "url"=>"", "family"=>6, "address"=>"200e::1/64"}, 
 "config_context"=>{}, 
 "created"=>"2018-07-19", 
 "last_updated"=>"2018-08-16T11:29:17.695587+11:00"
}
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: What is `vm.primary_ip.inspect`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get nested hash value.
Try to use this:

```
vm.dig('primary_ip', 'address')
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig

Comment: The `vm` isn't a hash, it's a [`NetboxClientRuby::Virtualization::VirtualMachine`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/netbox-client-ruby/0.5.2/NetboxClientRuby/Virtualization/VirtualMachine) similarly the `primary_id` is a [`NetboxClientRuby::IPAM::IpAddress`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/netbox-client-ruby/0.5.2/NetboxClientRuby/IPAM/IpAddress) so I doubt a simple `dig` will work.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using  `vm[:primary_ip].to_h["address"]`

Why I need to move that to_hash ?

Thanks for your help